# Скачка pdf файлов при парсинге

Tags: pdf, php, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день!

При парсинге данных с сайта, необходимо скачать pdf по ссылкам. Делаю это следующим способом:

```
function file_download($filename) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    flush();
    ob_clean();
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

Но такая конструкция подходит для скачивания одного файла. Как мне можно качать несколько файлов?

Comment: запустить скачку в цикле?

Comment: качайте по очереди. http протокол отдает файлы по одному на запрос.

Comment: Положите в архив, отдайте архив. Как вы себе представляете одновременную отдачу нескольких файлов?

Comment: Я тут как раз думаю об архиве. Не подскажите способы положить в архив?

Comment: Вы качаете с чужого сайта? или это Ваш сайт отдает?

Comment: С чужого сайта просто нужно собрать pdfки

Comment: >С чужого сайта просто нужно собрать pdfки

0) Тогда не очень понятен ваш код. Зачем `readfile()`, зачем отдаются заголовки? Вы парсите прямо из браузера и отдаёте сграбленное тоже юзеру в браузер? Это странный подход. Ваш граббер мог бы:

1) скчать и распарсить HTML

2) Пройтись по ссылкам из него, найти PDF'ки

3) запустить качалки этих PDF, можно одну, можно в несколько потоков

4) По окончании сформировать HTML с отчётом и ссылками на локально лежащие PDF и показать его юзеру

А с другой стороны, зачем тогда пункт 0? Отдавайте удалённые ссылки. Или что-то не так заданием.

Comment: Законность данного действия оставим на Вашей совести.

Да, Вам нужно будет все выкачать, один за одним. Но можете написать авторам/администраторам сайта и попросить.

Comment: 1) скчать и распарсить HTML
2) Пройтись по ссылкам из него, найти PDF'ки
Это все я уже сделал. Как раз нужно запустить качалки. Вопрос весь в этом. Как лучше это сделать? Юзеров никаких не будет кроме меня. Фактически, мне нужно просто спарсить ссылки с содержимым.

Comment: @hun7eee, так зачем вообще их отдавать в браузер? Качаем хоть последовательно, хот параллельно - это вообще не принципиально. И складываем на диск. Всё.

Comment: Вы можете подсказать, какими средствами я могу это сделать? Логику я представил. Инструменты не знаю.

Comment: Получаем ссылки на файлы. далее в цикле запускаем copy() и всё. Что за код в топике не ясно :)

Answer (score 2):

> Вы можете подсказать, какими средствами я могу это сделать?

Простите, не могу удержаться :)

```
$ perl -MHTML::Tree -e '`wget "$_"` for map {$_->attr("href")} HTML::Tree->new_from_url("http://test.com/")->look_down("_tag"=>"a","href"=>qr/\.pdf$/i);'
```

Всё :-) Это при условии, что в урлах PDF'ов полные ссылки, конечно, а не относительные.

Ну и на PHP, если в массиве `$hrefs` уже есть **полные** ссылки:

```
foreach( $hrefs as $href )
{
    file_put_contents
    ( 
        basename( $href ),
        file_get_contents( $href )
    );
}
```

Проверка имён на уникальность, место записи, сохранение информации об исходных URL, ошибки и прочее - на усмотрение.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!